# Silverlight Large File Downloader

Tags: silverlight, file, download

I've got an interesting one: the ability to marshal the download of files - many in the gigabyte region of data.

I have a silverlight website that allows the upload of large volumes of data (Gigs) using the following plugin: http://silverlightuploader.codeplex.com/

However, I also want to be able to allow users to download the same data too.  But I want to be able to restrict the amount of concurrent downloads.  Thus the idea of directly controlling a stream of data to the client via silverlight is compelling - as I don't want to directly install anything on the machine.

My question is: For the volume of data I am looking at retrieving is it appropriate to use the WebClient class (I can specify how many bytes into the http stream I want to read, so I can download it incrementally, and put some business rules round it checking how many people are currently downloading, and make it wait until user count has gone down...), or can I use sockets to keep the overhead down of HTTP?

Unless there is a project I've not found which does exactly this thing!

Cheers in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you download the data in chunks of some smaller size then the actual volume of the total file won't matter and it won't really matter what you use to do the downloading. For example, for a file of that size I would just use the WebClient class and download chucks of maybe 1 or 2 Mb at a time to a temporary storage file on disk. You'll have to keep track of how much you've got downloaded and where you need to start the next chuck from, but that isn't overly difficult a problem. You can use sockets but then you have to communicate with the web server yourself to get access to the file in the first place.

When a client connects to download the next chunk, that is where you would enforce your business logic concerning the number of concurrent users. There might be a library you can use to do all this but to be honest it's not a complex problem.